# Impact of variables available only for large geographic units in OLS and 2SLS

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, bias

I ran a series of OLS and 2SLS regressions to study the impact of several geographic variables on the dependent variable which is a share of workers of a particular type. The issue is that my unit of analysis is a small geographic area (district) but some variables are only available for larger areas (counties, and there are from 5 to 10 districts in a county). What consequences could I expect? Could this introduce bias?